# Google map crashing in few devices

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

My app is working fine in Moto G (Android 5.0.2) but crashing in Karbon spark (Android 5.1.1) and several other devices. This crash is due to MapFragment. Min skd is 17 so I am using MapFragment.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="com.dashboard.Activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dashboard.Activity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/api_key" />
```

build.gradle

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'`

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //App crashes here
}
```

------------error Log---------

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ com.dashboard.Activity.ActivityA}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
at com.dashboard.Activity.ActivityA.onCreate(ActivityA.java:62)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: @MsYvette added my complete log file...

Comment: I have the very same problem! Driving me insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known Google Map issue and it's observed when the device is in low memory condition. Google Map tries to create a file which fails in this case and MapFragment class can't be inflated.

Insert an SD card in Karbon spark(Android 5.1.1 ) device and the problem will not be observed. Google is still working on this issue and Fix is not available yet.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and it was driving me insane.

If you are running `findbyID(R.id.map)`; comment it out. Fragments should not be inflated that way.

Try chaning the class from `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment`

Also, the class which handles the map fragment, should extend `SupportMapFragment`, here is what mine looks like:

`public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

My MapFramgment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:name="com.mypackage.android.Views.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </fragment>
```

Good luck!

Comment: i have nothing en java except onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  and min sdk is 17 so i should use  MapFragment .but any how i tried with SupportMapFragment but no sucess

Comment: I have solved my problem...U can check my answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

I think, It is Google map api problem (**credential** value) 
Please check console and remove credential or add correct credential.

Please add api key value in **release folder** also (Please check via app folder)

Eg: api key : `AIzaSyBdVl-cTICSwYKrZ95SuvNw7dbMuDt1KG0`

Eg: credential:  `BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75`

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Comment: I have added API key and its running fine in moto but several of other devices its giving error

Comment: I think, your compiled version is running in Moto G. Please  add api key in release folder then build release all.

Comment: I have solved my problem...U can check my answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the SHA1 key for making a google map app.So visit Google Developer Console .
Here is the link so that you can refer to get it 
https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#installed_applications

Comment: I have solved my problem...U can check my answer for future reference